# table inside a div: how to vertically align texts in div and table

Tags: html, css

In this example, the two text blocks are vertically aligned on the left, but I can't find (after much research and many tries) how to align them on both sides:

```
<div style="text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">some wrapped (long enough) text
    <table style="margin-left: -7px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
        <tr><td>some wrapped (long enough) text</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is only a simplfied example; the table contains in fact multiple raws ans columns.
Vertical alignment concerns the text in the div on one hand and in the table, on the other hand.

Let me rephrase the question: can i resize a table inside a div so that it have a with of 100% relative to the browser and independently of the container div's margins and paddings?

It would be great if i could add something like width:(100%+7px);

Finally I came to this compromise/workaround: a thin border(1px), margins and padding in %, and calculated width in % too (> 100).

Comment: text-align : center; else i do not understand your request.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot make the table's width relative to the browser screen if it's wrapped inside another div.

Comment: That confirms what i thought - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is using `float:left` and `float:right`.
In your case, using 2 divs is enough to achieve what you need. Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR4sm/)

```
<div style="text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">
   <div style="float:left">some wrapped (long enough) text</div>
   <div style="float:right">some wrapped (long enough) text</div>
</div>
```

If you still want to use table. It's also possible, but i don't see the pointing of using table here

```
<div style="text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">
       <div style="float:left">some wrapped (long enough) text</div>
       <table style="float:right;margin-left: -7px; border: 3px solid red">
        <tr><td>some wrapped (long enough) text</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR4sm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **FLOAT**, don't use table, like this:

```
<div style="text-align: justify; padding: 10px;">
   <div style="float:left">text text text text</div>
   <div style="float:left">text text text text</div>
</div>
```

or "float:right" for the second one.

Don't forget to do:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

in the end (if necessary).

N.B: Don't use table unless it's necesessary (a statistic table for exemple).